Masking Desert from a map in google earth engine
I'm an urban planner with very limited knowledge of Java scripts. I'm working on a paper to predict the urban growth of Doha,Qatar. My problem is that the maps of built-up areas include the desert. How do I mask the desert from the map?
I tried to generate built-up area maps for different years from 1990-2020,the problem is that the built-up area includes the desert area; how to exclude it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
